# possible eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix such that $A^2=A^t$. Then prove that possible **real** eigenvalues of $A$ are $0,1$.

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^2$ is eigenvalue of $A^2$.

As $A^2=A^t$, $\lambda^2$ is eigenvalue of $A^t$..

Eigenvalue of $A$ are same as eigenvalue of $A^t$..

So, real eigenvalues of $A^t$  are $\{\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_r,\lambda_1^2,\cdots,\lambda_r^2\}$.

As number of real eigenvalues are fixed we must have $\lambda_i^2=\lambda_i$ or $\lambda_j$ or $\lambda_j^2$..

$\lambda_i^2=\lambda_j^2$ and $\lambda_i\neq \lambda_j$ implies $\lambda_i=-\lambda_j$ i do not see any contradiction here..

$\lambda_i^2=\lambda_j$ i do not know what to conclude...

$\lambda_i^2=\lambda_i$ then $\lambda_i=0$ or $1$.. which is what i want..

Help me to clear this...

Comment: @amd I don't agree to close this question because the answers in the previous "similar questions" are far from satisfying.

Comment: @JeanMarie : Please vote to reopen

Comment: Where must I vote ?

Comment: Just below the content of the question there are options.. share, cite, edit, reopen.. Please click reopen @JeanMarie

Comment: I have not the "reopen" option ; not enough ranking may be...

Comment: @JeanMarie : That is fine... Thanks for your support... I felt bad when this question is closed as duplicate of other question which has no effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should consider the fact that corresponding eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^2$ are the same. So these $\lambda$ and $\lambda^2$ are both eigenvalues of  the same eigenvectors. Since eigenvalues must be unique, then $\lambda = \lambda^2$, which leads $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda = 1$.

EDIT:

Suppose $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue of $A$, with eigenvector $v$; then $Av=\lambda v$ and, easily, also $A^2v=\lambda^2v$. Therefore
$$
A^tv=A^2v=\lambda^2v
$$
and so $v^tA=\lambda^2v^t$. Hence
$$
v^tAv=\lambda^2(v^tv)
$$
but, on the other hand,
$$
v^tAv=v^t(\lambda v)=\lambda(v^tv)
$$
Since $v^tv\ne0$, we get $\lambda^2=\lambda$.

Comment: I missed this point it seems.. "$\lambda$ and $\lambda^2$ are eigenvalues of same eigenvector"

Comment: $Av=\lambda v$ implies $A^2v=\lambda^2 v$ i.e., $A^t v=\lambda^2 v$.. Now i have to see if $A v=\lambda v$ implies $A^t v=\lambda v$...

Comment: @cello see the edit.

Comment: Ok Ok... So, we are not saying $Av=\lambda v$ implies $A^t v=\lambda v$.. we are only saying that $\lambda=\lambda^2$. fine.. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, so is $\lambda^2$, and so is, for the same reason,  $\lambda^{4}$, $\lambda^{8}$... or any $\lambda^{2^k}$.

Thus, in the case $\lambda$ is not in $\{-1,0,1\}$, it would generate an infinite spectrum, which cannot be.

It remains the case $\lambda=-1$ that has to be eliminated, because all eigenvalues of $A$ are eigenvalues of $A^2$, and these are $\geq 0$.

Comment: I did not understand last line... Suppose $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $-1$ is also an eigenvalue of $A^2$ then what?

Comment: All eigenvalues of $A$ are eigenvalues of $A^2$. But all eigenvalues of $A^2$ are positive. Thus, it is impossible for an eigenvalue of $A$ to be negative.

Comment: @JeanMarie How do you prove that the real eigenvalues of $A^2$ are $\geq 0$ ? I need to triangularize $A$ to see that, do you have a different proof ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM : Now i am also a bit confused... Is it true that for any $A^2$ eigenvalues are non negative?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM You may be right ! Do we agree that all this is for the elimination of root $-1$, n'est ce pas ? I will return to it on the evening.

Comment: @JeanMarie I think you botched up the end of the proof. The real eigenvalues of $A^2$ need not be nonnegative (if $i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$). It is worth noting that $\dim \ker A+I_n=\dim \ker A^T+I_n=\dim \ker A^2+I_n$

Comment: @JeanMarie (continued) after some lengthy manipulations, I found an elegant proof that $-1$ cannot be an eigenvalue. Suppose that $Av=-v$. Then $A^Tv=A^2v=A(Av)=-Av=v$. Since $A^2=A^T$, $A$ commutes with $A^T$ ($AA^T=A^TA$), which allows me to "break some symmetry". Indeed, $0\leq ||Av||^2 = v^TA^TAv=v^TAA^Tv=v^TAv=-v^Tv=-||v||^2$. Hence $v=0$ !

Comment: @cello see my last comment for a proof that $-1$ cannot be an eigenvalue.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM : Thanks.. Got it

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM splendid proof. I felt intuitively that one had to deal with quadratic forms to get out of this marsh: you found the path... Thank you very much for having pointed out the deficiency of my arguments.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM The fact that a matrix is _normal_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix allows a certain number of good properties.